# Return weekday from user input in a date TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a form where I want to automatically populate a TextBox with the day of the week based on the date input by a user in another TextBox with type="date".  I have successfully done this in javascript, however I'm new to c# and haven't been able to figure it out.

here is a test .aspx file to use:

```
<form runat="server" id="test">
    <label for="beginning_date">beginning day & date</label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="beginning_day" onChange="GetBeginningDay" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:textBox runat="server" ID="beginning_date" type="date" onChange="GetBeginningDay"></asp:textBox>
</form>
```

I want to populate the TextBox "beginning_day" based on the date input in TextBox "Beginning_Date".

EDIT TO ADD:

none of the proposed solutions were working for me.  I managed to get the following code together that accomplishes what I need...

```
protected void GetBeginningDay(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                
            beginning_day.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(beginning_date.Text).DayOfWeek.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

...however I can't get AutoPostBack to fire and the code-behind only executes when I hit the submit button and a postback is triggered due to an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your markup slightly, and this should be all that you need:

```
<label for="beginning_date">beginning day & date</label>    
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="beginning_date" OnTextChanged="beginning_date_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" type="date" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="beginning_day" ReadOnly="true" />
```

Note that "onChange" has been changed to use the ASP.NET TextBox's event, OnTextChanged.  You can determine whether AutoPostBack should be set to true, but I assume that it should be.  If false, AutoPostBack will wait till the form is submitted to raise the event, and when true, the event is raised immediately.

Also, I've removed the form as WebForms typically has one already.

Here is the code behind:

```
protected void beginning_date_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime date;
    DateTime.TryParse(beginning_date.Text, out date);

    beginning_day.Text = date.DayOfWeek.ToString();
}
```

You may need additional logic, but this is the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Do you think it's worth the extra work going forward to transfer the event to be server-side rather than client-side?  The idea behind it was to eliminate the need for a javascript file and centralize all the functions for the form in one code-behind file.

Comment: I suppose it depends, but I'd probably stick with JavaScript unless you have more to do than just update that one input element.

Comment: I'm trying to put this into my code-behind.  I'm assuming to need to change
    var input = (TextBox)sender;
to get it to work with my controls, but I'm not sure what it to change it to

Comment: No, you should not need to change that line.  Anyways, I've updated my original code to be a bit more clear.

Comment: still not working.  When I was looking around, I found that the DateTime uses a different date format (yyyy, mm, dd) than the TextBox with type=Date (dd/mm/yyy).  Do you think that might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do this using server side asp.net C# code.

onChange event is a client side JavaScript event which cannot populate server side (C#) code without __doPostback() call. Better way of doing this is to use OnTextChanged event with AutoPostback property.

OnTextChanged event cannot work without AutoPostBack="true".

.aspx file

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" TextMode="Date" OnTextChanged="GetBeginningDay"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

.aspx.cs file (code behind file)

```
protected void GetBeginningDay(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userInput = TextBox1.Text;
    DateTime dateTime;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(userInput, out dateTime))
    {
        TextBox2.Text = dateTime.DayOfWeek.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: OnTextChanged event will fire when AutoPostBack is set to false (unless the text never changed), but it won't fire until something else has raised a postback.